# jeasyui framework and print var for link. - JQUERY / PHP

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-easyui

I like to print a var with doc number in a modal dialog from [jeasyui](http://www.jeasyui.com/) framework. I know how I can put the var in a [textbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_box) but have still problems to print the var (with ID of the doc number) in the hyperlink, does somebody know how I can print the var the same as the echo in php.

thanks a LOT!,

Johan.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function editDoc(){
            var row = $('#dg').datagrid('getSelected');
            if (row){
                $('#dlg').dialog('open').dialog('setTitle','Edit Documents');
                $('#fm').form('load',row);
                url = 'easyui/update_doc.php?HID='+row.HID;

            }
        }
        function SaveDocInfo(){
            $('#fm').form('submit',{
                url: url,
                onSubmit: function(){
                    return $(this).form('validate');
                },
                success: function(result){
                    var result = eval('('+result+')');
                    if (result.success){
                        $('#dlg').dialog('close');      // close the dialog
                        $('#dg').datagrid('reload');    // reload the user data
                    } else {
                        $.messager.show({
                            title: 'Error',
                            msg: result.msg
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dlg2" class="easyui-dialog" closed="true" title="Basic Dialog" data-options="iconCls:'icon-save'" style="width:400px;height:200px;padding:10px"> The dialog content. </div>
<h2>DocumentSearch</h2>
    <table id="dg" title="Documents" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:800px;height:1000px"
            url="easyui/get_documents.php"
            toolbar="#toolbar" pagination="true"
            rownumbers="true" fitColumns="true" singleSelect="true" pagesize="30">
      <thead>
            <tr>
                <th field="HID" width="50">HID</th>
                <th field="Type" width="50">Type</th>
                <th field="DocumentDate" width="100">DocumentDate</th>
                <th field="Name" width="150">Account</th>
                <th field="Subject" width="200">Subject</th>
                <th field="AmountFC" width="60">Amount</th>
                <th field="PurchaseInvoiceNumber" width="60">Booking</th>

            </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
    <div id="toolbar">
<a href="#" class="easyui-linkbutton" iconCls="icon-edit" plain="true" onclick="editDoc()">Edit Document</a>




    </div>

<div id="dlg" class="easyui-dialog" style="width:600px;height:400px;padding:10px 20px"
            closed="true" buttons="#dlg-buttons">
        <div class="ftitle">DocumentInformation</div>
  <form id="fm" method="post" novalidate>
            <div class="fitem"> 

  <table width="400" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>HID</td>
        <td><input name="HID" type="" class="easyui-validatebox"  readonly="True" data-options="min:0,precision:2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>TYPE</td>
        <td>    <select class="easyui-combobox" name="Type" data-options="
                    url:'combobox_data2.php',
                    method:'get',
                    valueField:'Type',
                    textField:'Type',
                    panelHeight:'auto',
                    width:300">   
    </select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>ACCOUNT</td>
        <td>
        <input class="easyui-combobox" name="Account"
            data-options="
                    url:'combobox_data1.php',
                    method:'get',
                    valueField:'ID',
                    textField:'Name',
                    panelHeight:'auto',
                    width:300">               <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="$('#dlg2').dialog('open')">AddNew</a>

        </td>
      </tr>
          <tr>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td><input name="DocumentDate" type="" class="easyui-validatebox" style="width:300px"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SUBJECT</td>
        <td><input name="Subject" type="" class="easyui-validatebox" style="width:300px"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>AMOUNT</td>
        <td><input name="AmountFC" type="text" class="easyui-numberbox" data-options="min:0,precision:2">
        </td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td>Link</td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo "http://XX.XXX.XXX.XX/FileServer/".$_SESSION[AdminID]."/Documents/<??????????????>.pdf"; ?>" target="_new"><?php echo "DocLink"; ?></a></td>
      </tr>
        <tr>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </form>
```

Comment: can you upload the code at http://fiddle.net/ so the others can test your code?

Comment: provide your code of update_doc.php can help more

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this

```
<a href="<?php echo 'http://XX.XXX.XXX.XX/FileServer/'.$_SESSION[AdminID].'/Documents/'.$var_doc-id.'pdf'; ?>" target="_new">
```